# BrowserRouter as a component creates lots of Router context errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have put BrowserRouter into a component called Router and for some reason when I use it that way all sorts of errors relating to functions may only be used in the context of a `<Router>` component appear. I was just wondering why this happens?

For example:

This works:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<HomeView />} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This doesn't:

```
// Router Component
const Router = (props) => {

    // Return component
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            {props.children}
        </BrowserRouter>
    );

};

// Export
export default Router;
```

```
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<HomeView />} />
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

Errors produced:

[image]

Actual Code:

index.js

```
// Styles
import '../components/ava-css-main/index.scss';

// Packages
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
//import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Router } from '@avaeventsltd/ava-components';

// Comonents
import Container from './Container';
import ErrorBoundary from './ErrorBoundary';

// Render
const container = document.getElementById('application');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<Router>

        <Container/>

</Router>);
```

container.js

```
// Imports
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './container.scss';

// Views
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView';
import SubmitButtonView from '../views/SubmitButtonView';
import HeaderView from '../views/HeaderView';
import SideNavigationView from '../views/SideNavigationView';
import TopNavigationView from '../views/TopNavigationView';

import PageNotFound from '../views/PageNotFound';

// Components
import LibraryHeader from '../LibraryHeader';
import { TopNavigation } from '@avaeventsltd/ava-components';

// Container component
const Container = () => {

    return (

        <div className="container">

            <LibraryHeader />

            <TopNavigation items={[
                {
                    title: "Buttons",
                    link: "",
                    submenu: [{
                        title: "Submit Button",
                        link: "/buttons/submit"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    title: "Blocks",
                    link: "",
                    submenu: [{
                        title: "Header",
                        link: "/blocks/header"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    title: "Navigation",
                    link: "",
                    submenu: [{
                        title: "Side Navigation",
                        link: "/navigation/side"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Top Navigation",
                        link: "/navigation/top"
                    }]
                }
            ]} />

            <div className="container-wrapper">

                <div className="container-content-wrapper">

                    <Routes>

                        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
                        <Route path="/" element={<HomeView />} />
                        <Route path="/buttons/submit" element={<SubmitButtonView />} />
                        <Route path="/blocks/header" element={<HeaderView />} />
                        <Route path="/navigation/side" element={<SideNavigationView />} />
                        <Route path="/navigation/top" element={<TopNavigationView />} />

                    </Routes>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    );

};

export default Container;
```

router component:

```
// Imports
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Router Component
const Router = (props) => {

    // Return component
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            {props.children}
        </BrowserRouter>
    );

};

// Export
export default Router;
```

Comment: are you sure `Router` might not be import from `react-router-dom`

Comment: What ***actual*** errors are being produced? Are you sure you are using the correct `Router` component? Can you edit your question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: @OkanKaradag the only thing I am importing from react-router-dom is BrowserRouter like so `import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: @DrewReese I have added screenshots of the actual errors and also added all the code required (index.js, container.js, router component) to recreate. The `Router` component is one that I have created that for the moment is just a component with `BrowserRouter` in it.